# How to use lambda to mutiple dictionary values?

Tags: python, lambda

so i met a question during learning python. lets say i have a dictionary a

```
a = {'Andy':[2,4,6,8],'Bryce':[1,2,3], 'Charile': [3,6], 'David':[10], 'Elaine' :[5,10]}
```

how can i use lambda to multiple 2 to every number in a and return a new dict?

i tried `new_a= list(map(lambda x: x * 2, a.values()))` however, it return a list like `[[2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 3, 6], [10, 10], [5, 10, 5, 10]]`

the new dict I want is actully:

```
new_a =  {'Andy':[4,8,12,16],'Bryce'，[2,4,6], 'Charile': [6,12], 'David':[20], 'Elaine' :[10,20]}
```

Comment: A dict comprehension will do the trick. ie, `new_a  = {key: [item  * 2 for item in value] for key, value in a.items()}`

Comment: Whenever you find yourself writing `map(lambda…`, stop and ask whether this could be a comprehension. `map` is great when you already have a function lying around, but when you're trying to apply an expression and then have to wrap that expression up in a function just so you can pass that function to `map`… that's two extra steps that just cancel each other out.

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple.

Changing existing dict:

```
for key, value in a.items():
  a[key] = [2 * item for item in value]
```

Creating a new dict with the updated values:

```
b = dict()
for key, value in a.items():
  b[key] = [2 * item for item in value]
```

Using Dictionary comprehension

```
b = {key: [2 * item for item in value] for key, value in a.items()}
```

No idea what you need Lambda for here. This is done much easier without.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
a = {'Andy':[2,4,6,8],'Bryce':[1,2,3], 'Charile': [3,6], 'David':[10], 'Elaine' :[5,10]}

new_a = dict(list((key, list(map(lambda i:i*2, value))) for key, value in a.items()))
```

Output:

```
{'Andy': [4, 8, 12, 16], 'Bryce': [2, 4, 6], 'Charile': [6, 12], 'David': [20], 'Elaine': [10, 20]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_dict(l1, l2, l3):
    return {e[0]:max(e[1], e[2]) for e in zip(l1, l2, l3)}
```

Using Dictionary Comprehension:
this is quite a short way ))
you can choose which items you want as keys or value.

Answer (score 0):

```
# using lambda:
clients = ["A", "B", "C"]
spending_rate = [83724, 64728, 3822]
entry_year = [1999, 2010, 2019]
analyzes = dict(
    zip(
        clients,
        map(
            lambda x : x,
            zip(spending_rate, entry_year)
        )
    )
)
print(analyzes)
```